# before and after module in route.xml - magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

can anyone explain what is the right situation to use **before** and **after** attribute in **route.xml**?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="routename" frontName="routename">
            <module name="vendor_module" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I am looking well explain answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need  to use a before or after tag to control the order, Magento will check for matches.

Using the after tag above ensures Magento checks our module after the `Magento_Backend` module. Without this, it would be possible for us to accidentally create a controller file that replaced the core controllers in `vendor/magento/module-backend/Controller` and before tag is as same as reverse to `after`.

For more information you can also refer link http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_advanced_routing

Answer (score 5):

Magento provide the attribute `before/after` to config the module sort order which define what module controller will be find first. This is the logic for the **controller rewrite**.

For example, if we want to rewrite the controller `customer/account/login`, we will define more route in the `routes.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <!--Use router 'standard' for frontend route-->
   <router id="standard">
       <route id="customer">
           <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Customer" />
       </route>
   </router>
</config>
```

Add the controller file: `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Account/Login.php`

So the frontController will find the Login action in our module **first**, if it’s found, it will run, and the Login action of Magento_Customer will **not be run**. Then we are successful rewrite a controller.